# Удалить слово менее N букв в конце предложения

Tags: php

```html
if(mb_strlen($text_original,'UTF-8') >= 60){
$text1 = mb_substr($text_original, 0, 57);   //Обрезаем текст
$words=explode(" ", $text1);             //Разбиваем по словам 
array_splice($words,-1);                //Удаляем последнее слово 

$last=rtrim(array_pop($words), '!,.-:');      //Получаем последнее слово 

$text = implode(" ", $words).' '.$last.'…';

}
```

Как в данном примере получить последнее слово более N букв?
Например, сейчас выводится: "Белеет парус одинокий в тумане моря голубом.Что ищет он в..." А нужно: "Белеет парус одинокий в тумане моря голубом.Что ищет..."
Т.е. в данном случае нужно убрать в конце все слова менее 3-х букв.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/Q02cXL/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$string="Белеет парус одинокой В тумане моря голубом!.. Что ищет он в стране далекой? Что кинул он в краю родном?.. Играют волны — ветер свищет, И мачта гнется и скрыпит... Увы! он счастия не ищет, И не от счастия бежит! Под ним струя светлей лазури, Над ним луч солнца золотой... А он, мятежный, просит бури, Как будто в бурях есть покой!";

echo cut_str($string, 165, 3);

/**
 * @param $string - входная строка
 * @param $length - примерная длина обрезанной строки
 * @param $max_tail - слова до какой длины должны быть обрезаны в конце предложения
 * @return bool|string
 */
function cut_str($string, $length, $max_tail)
{
    $string = strip_tags($string);
    $string = substr($string, 0, $length);
    $string = substr($string, 0, strrpos($string, ' '));
    $words=array_map('trim', explode(' ', $string));
    $ok=false;
    $words_quantity=count($words)-1;
    while ($ok===false){
        if($words_quantity < 0) $ok=true;
        $word=$words[$words_quantity];
        if (!empty($word) && iconv_strlen($word) > $max_tail){
            $ok=true;
            continue;
        }
        unset($words[$words_quantity]);
        $words_quantity--;
    }
    if (count($words)===0) return false;
    $string=implode(' ', $words);
    $string = rtrim($string, "!:?,.-");
    $string.="… ";

    return $string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Написал вариант с рекурсивной функцией:

```
$int = 3; // Минимальное количество букв в последнем слове
$text = 'Белеет парус одинокий в тумане моря голубом.Что ищет он в...';
foo($text, $int);

echo $text; // Белеет парус одинокий в тумане моря голубом.Что ищет


function foo(&$text, $int) {
    $text = preg_replace('~(?<=\p{P})(?=\p{L})~u', ' ', $text);
    $words = explode(' ', $text);    
    $last = rtrim(array_pop($words), '?!:,.-');

    if (mb_strlen($last, 'UTF-8') < $int) {
        $text = join(' ', $words);
        foo($text, $int);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, Ваш вариант тоже работает.